# Is the below possible using Adobe Illustrator. It yes, then how?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I am a novice using Adobe Illustrator. I need to convert this to the colors as shown in the 2nd image. The font is called Advio. Any help?

This is what I have so far:

[image: Source Image]
This is what I want to achieve: (the varying colors)

[image: Target Image. This what I want.]

Comment: Can't you select the shapes that have a gradient and change them? See [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html) for more info on using gradients in Illustrator

Comment: What have you tried? Please give us some more information, as-is, it's almost impossible to answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: I tried changing colors & gradients but it does not bring the same effect as in the 2nd image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands it is a tutorial request. Please tell us what you've tried and at which point exactly you got stuck or what exact tool you're experiencing trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the eyedropper tool to sample each of the colours before you start, and add these as a new colour swatches. That way you will get a colour match when you edit the gradients. You can click and drag the colours from the toolbar into the swatches window.

[image]

Select the gradient filled shape, choose the gradient tool, then edit the gradient. I have started off with some very different colours so you can see the changes.

[image]

You can also click and drag on the gradient itself, to change its size/position, or rotate it.

[image]